# Split-view application, how do dismiss some controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have to change the elements marked in the pictures. How would I do that!

It is navigationBar and navigation element probably.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root view controller for the master view controller is a `UINavigationController`, this is what gives the grey navigation bar.

Use the `navigationBar` property of the navigation controller to modify the visual appearance.

Use `navigationBarHidden` on the navigation controller to hide it all together. Or simply skip the navigation controller wrapper and set the table view directly as the master controller on your split view controller.